# onDelete() method executes two times, What will be the issue?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';

class deleteTodo extends Component {


    onDelete(){
        console.log("delete")
        axios.post('http://localhost:4000/todos/delete/'+this.props.match.params.id)
            .then(res => console.log(res.data));

        this.props.history.push('/');

    }

    render() {
        return (
                <div>
                    {this.onDelete()}

                </div>


        )
    }
}

export default deleteTodo
```

Comment: Why is deleteTodo a component instead of a function

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Because i want to make it handle delete operations of todo app. So i have made component.

Comment: You can make use of button and add an onClick on it. you should never have async code in render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: render() is called multiple times for various reasons, see https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render for more details.

You might try using `componentDidMount()` for the deletion request if it should be done once and immediately after the component is mounted.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';

class deleteTodo extends Component {


    componentDidMount(){
        console.log("delete")
        axios.post('http://localhost:4000/todos/delete/'+this.props.match.params.id)
            .then(res => console.log(res.data));

        this.props.history.push('/');

    }

    render() {
        return (
                <div></div>
        )
    }
}

export default deleteTodo
```

I still think this is a really weird way of approaching your desired effect.

Comment: Its working fine with this omponentDidMount().  What will be the good way to handle this ??? Please elaborate, i am new to react js

Comment: Tbh I haven't been using react js for a long time so im not the best one to answer. But my guess would be that handling the POST request somewhere else is a better option. E.g. in the section where you add the deleteTodo component in order to perform the deletion task